# How to make "generic method declaration" to accept subclasses

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns, collections

I have a interface method:

```
List<User> getUsers(Query query);
```

and its implementation:

```
List<User> getUsers(Query query){
..
return users;
}
```

I can use it without problems:

```
Query q = new Query(..);
List<User> users = getUsers(q);
```

Now I create a subclass of Query:

```
class UserQuery extens Query{..}
```

and want to pass an instance of this subclass into getUsers()-method:

```
UserQuery uq = new UserQuery(..);
List<User> users = getUsers(uq); // does not work, as getUsers accepts only "Query"-objects
```

As defined in the interface, getUsers() only accepts a "Query"-object and not its subclass.

**How can I make the method more generic, so it can accepts Query-Objects but also all its subclasses ?**

I tried this, but it is not possible in Java:

Interface:

```
// is not possible in java
List<User> getUsers(<E extends Query> query);

// also not possible in java
List<User> getUsers(Object<? extends MarketdataQuery> query);
```

Implementation:

```
// is not possible in java
List<User> getUsers(<E extends Query> query){
..
return users;
}
```

**

### EDIT:

**

It works only when I pass a "Query"-Object:

```
// This works: 
Query q = new UserQuery(..); 
List<User> users = getUsers(q);


// This does not work:
UserQuery uq = new UserQuery(..);
List<User> users = getUsers(uq);
```

The get the actual Query-Object, I have to use a cast, so I cannot pass a UserQuery into the method..

```
List<User> getUsers(Query query){
    UserQuery uq = (UserQuery) query;
    return users;
}
```

Comment: This method: List<User> getUsers(Query query);  accepts all Query and its subclasses so It should work, something else is wrong with your code. maybe you have a compile error here: 'class UserQuery extens Query{..}'

Answer (score 1):

You can generify method, not only the parameter. This will do the work:

```
<E extends Query> List<User> getUsers(E query);
```

Now `query` can be of type `Query` or any other subclass of it.

Comment: I can use `getUsers(Query query)` without using generics..however, I must **cast** `query` to get access to `UserQuery`-Properties..I dont see another solution..when I use your suggestion, I also have to do a cast (`UserQuery q = (Query) query;`) ..

Comment: "you have to" is wrong. OP doesn't not have to. They _can_, though.

Comment: ok.. So your whole question is wrong. You are able to pass the SubQuery to your method

Comment: @nimo23 No, you don't need to cast. Like beatrice already wrote under your question: your issue is somethere else. Check the typo she mentioned.

Comment: Not, it's a "design question". The code works. I am able to pass the "SubQuery" to the method. However, to get its properties, I have to cast. So even when using generic method declaration with `E query`, I have to cast `E` to `UserQuery`..

Comment: @nimo23 Oh, ok, I didn't thought you were blatantly lying about your issue. You ___wrote___ multiple times you can't pass `UserQuery`. Your whole question has _nothing_ to do with accessing properties of a subclass inside a method that accepts a parent type.

Comment: You did not understand: I **cannot** pass UserQuery when using `List<User> getUsers(<E extends Query> query)` or when using `UserQuery uq = new UserQuery(..);
List<User> users = getUsers(uq);` as I described above..however, when using `Query q = new UserQuery(..);
List<User> users = getUsers(q);`, I **can** pass, BUT I have to cast it again within the method to get props of UserQuery. There is no way to pass UserQuery-Object within the method, only when I pass it through its supertype.

Comment: @Tom indeed, I need to cast!